# ORACLE, CONNECT BY ROWNUM FROM DUAL, MULTIPLE COLUMN

Tags: sql, oracle

I need 2 columns, the first column contains int numbers 1 -100 and the second column contains 001-100.

I have tried this query,
but the result is the second column is not 001 to 100

```
SELECT ROWNUM AS Nomor, to_char (ROWNUM) AS No_Row
FROM DUAL 
CONNECT BY ROWNUM >= '001' AND ROWNUM <= 100;
```

[image: but the result is like this]

[image: I want results like this]

How can I do that?
Can somebody help me

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT ROWNUM AS Nomor, to_char(ROWNUM, '000') AS No_Row
```

That is, you want a format for `to_char()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lpad` and `hiearchical query` as follows:

```
select level as rn,
       lpad(level,3,0) as rn_padded
  from dual
connect by level <= 100
```

[Db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4a7d5f6215b10640b399a58cdecbe901)

Cheers!!